# remove print button in odoo report

Tags: printing, report, odoo, qweb

I create report with the type (qweb-html) in odoo 14 , and I want to remove the default print button from it , as in the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to override this template:

> ```
> <t t-name="report.client_action.ControlButtons">
>     <div class="o_report_buttons">
>         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary o_report_print" title="Print">Print</button>
>     </div>
> </t>
> ```

Source:
addons/web/static/src/xml/report.xml

Just comment the line:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary o_report_print" title="Print">Print</button>
```